# Securing strings that have usernames and passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing an API. I need to provide the username and password for an account the API will connect to.

```
        profile.APIUsername = "myusername";
        profile.APIPassword = "mypassword";
```

in the API documentation is has this warning.

```
/*
         WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
         Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
         Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
         encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
         that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
         */
```

of course I agree, so how can I secure these and not put plain text in the production code?? Do I store them in a database? but how do I encrypt/decrypt them?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the username and password in your Web.config file and then encrypt those settings in the Web.config.

Here's a simple way to encrypt them: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/08/encrypting-custom-configuration-sections.aspx

Comment: Can a class in a separate Dll, access the web.config file if it is in the same solution? This class is in a different layer than my web layer

Comment: @twal Yes, you can access the config file through the ConfigurationManager class from a seperate DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the solutions provided by mkchandler and Conrad Frix are your best bet as they are both secure and fully supported by the framework. Keep in mind that those options will work great *when you have control over the web servers and can run the tool to encrypt the config file directly on the machine where the web.config will reside in production*. This is typically not a problem if you own the servers (as opposed to using a hosting provider.) Also keep in mind that if you have a web farm you will need to encrypt the value on each machine as those solutions use a machine specific key to encrypt the values.

If you don't have the luxury of controlling the web servers then you might want to encrypt the values with your own program, store them encrypted in your web.config and decrypt them at runtime. This is less than ideal but would work if you don't have control of the web servers. There are plenty of classes in .NET to encrypt values that should help you if you decide to go this route (shameless plug - [here is an example](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-a-string-in-C-Sharp) on how to use the .NET classes encrypt/decrypt strings).

Answer (score 0):

twal,

you could take a look at this page that gives a simple insight using connection strings in the web.config as an example. it majors on both the **RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider** and **DataProtectionConfigurationProvider**, both of which are pretty secure.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx

should be applicable to what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Starting With ASP.NET 2.0 I did this using [encrypted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) configuration sections. Its nice because your code just uses the Configuration the same way regardless of if its encrypted or not and ASP.NET takes care of decrypting it at run time.